# Alternate of ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler in Angular

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler in Angular, but according to their documentation,
they require 'unsafe-eval' for the script-src.

Is there any alternative that anyone knows about?

I researched: https://formatjs.io/docs/intl-messageformat/

But it doesn't seem to have any API reference for Angular.
Anyone knows any better solution?

Comment: Since CSP is now more and more required this should get more attention

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem and used FormatJs to use it in a TranslateCompiler. It supports Angular 13 and 14. If you are using an earlier Angular version, you can just copy this file into your code [translate-format-js-compiler.ts](https://github.com/stefanseeger/ngx-translate-formatjs-compiler/blob/main/src/lib/translate-format-js-compiler.ts) and it should work.

Otherwise, this is the npm dependency: [ngx-translate-formatjs-compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-translate-formatjs-compiler)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with building the project with webpack, maybe you can try to use [ngx-translate-parser-plural-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-translate-parser-plural-select)

Instead of using a compiler like this...

```
compiler: {
     provide: TranslateCompiler,
     useClass: TranslateMessageFormatCompiler
}
```

...you have to define parser, like this:

```
parser: {
     provide: TranslateParser,
     useClass: TranslateICUParser
}
```

Everything else should be untouched.